# Read latests posts on a public Facebook page

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to use the Facebook SDK or Graph API to read the latest posts/updates on a public Facebook page without the need for login? Browsing to the page while not logged in with a standard browser gives me access to all the latests posts, but can I this via the Facebook API's?

Thank you
Søren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you only need an **App Access Token** for the Page feed.

Information (with code) about the feed: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/feed

Information about Access Tokens: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens